# Opencart HTTP500 Error Module "Social Login (powered by SocialAll) [vQ-Mod]"

Tags: php, codeigniter, opencart

I have a problem when I want to install social login module, there are http500 error message, how can I fix this? thank you

1. Module

[image]

2. Click Edit Module Social Login and Error HTTP 500,Why?
   [image]

Comment: Could you please translate the error message?

Comment: if I click the edit button after I install the module and an show error  HTTP500 ?

Comment: Help me please...